# Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use, when trying to login?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a simple login just for the moment and when I try to login I get this error

`Cannot declare class App\Models\User, because the name is already in use`

In my User Model, this is the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable

{

    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [

        'username', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [

        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [

        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

The error says on this line

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

This is my submit method on my Login.vue

```
submit() {
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.post('/login', {
                username: this.form.username,
                password: this.form.password,
            }).then(() => this.loading = false)
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have another class named `User` under the namespace `App\Models` just delete it

Comment: @Saly3301 if I remove that it says `Class 'App\Models\Authenticatable' not found`

Comment: What? What did you remove? I said delete the other file (you didn't include in the question) not the line

Comment: @Saly3301 oh lol I removed the line `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`, that is the only User file I have, it's in the folder `app/Models`

Comment: Wouldn't make sense, run `composer dumpautoload` please

Comment: @Saly3301 now I'm gettin `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class '\App\User' not found`

Comment: @Saly3301 I usually move all my models into a Models folder I create, just to have them more organized, I've done this in another project without issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201124/discussion-between-nancy-and-saly-3301).